# R error with h2o-ensemble getting a bad request (Temp ID RTMP_5 already exists) when creating h2o ensemble model even tough it worked before

Tags: r, machine-learning, bad-request, h2o

Hi I began to use the package h2o ensemble (here :https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/tree/master/h2o-r/ensemble for some data analysis and tried a demo code.

The code worked well before :

```
## ## setting up h2o
library(h2oEnsemble)
nodes <- 2 ## number of processes
localH2O <-  h2o.init(nthreads=nodes)

## ## simulated data set
dat <- matrix(rnorm(6e3), ncol=3, dimnames=list(NULL, c("W", "X", "Y")))
dat <- as.data.frame(dat)
Z <- as.factor(rbinom(nrow(dat), size=1, prob=plogis(.2+.1*dat$W-.2*dat$X)))
dat <- cbind(dat, Z=Z)
## W,X,Y: Input
## Z: output
dat.app <- dat[1:1e3, ]
dat.val <- dat[1e3+(1:1e3), ]

## ## h2o procedure
dat.h2o.app <- as.h2o(localH2O, dat.app) ## learning
dat.h2o.val <- as.h2o(localH2O, dat.val) ## validation

library.h2o <- c("h2o.deeplearning.Tanh",
                 "h2o.randomForest.1000x100")

h2o.randomForest.1000x100 <- function(...,ntrees=1000,nbins=100) {
    h2oEnsemble::h2o.randomForest.wrapper(..., ntrees=ntrees, nbins=nbins,seed=1)
}
h2o.deeplearning.Tanh <- function(...,hidden=c(200, 200,200),activation="Tanh" ) {
    h2oEnsemble::h2o.deeplearning.wrapper(..., hidden=hidden,    activation=activation,seed=1)
}
h2o.model <- h2o.ensemble(y="Z", x=c("W", "X", "Y"),
                          training_frame=dat.h2o.app,
                          family="binomial",
                          learner=library.h2o,
                          cvControl=list(V=10, shuffle=TRUE),
                          metalearner="h2o.glm.wrapper") # getting the 400 bad request

h2o.pred.val <- predict(h2o.model, newdat=dat.h2o.val)$pred
table((h2o.pred.val>0.5)+0, dat.val$Z)
```

and it suddenly throw me a 400 bad request (RTMP_5 already exist)

```
R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10) -- "Wooden Christmas-Tree"
Copyright (C) 2015 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

> ## ## setting up h2o
> library(h2oEnsemble)
> nodes <- 2 ## number of processes
> localH2O <-  h2o.init(nthreads=nodes)
Successfully connected to http://127.0.0.1:54321/ 

R is connected to the H2O cluster: 
    H2O cluster uptime:         9 days 19 hours 
    H2O cluster version:        3.6.0.8 
    H2O cluster name:           H2O_started_from_R_root_afl027 
    H2O cluster total nodes:    1 
    H2O cluster total memory:   6.98 GB 
    H2O cluster total cores:    6 
    H2O cluster allowed cores:  2 
    H2O cluster healthy:        TRUE 

> 
> ## ## simulated data set
> dat <- matrix(rnorm(6e3), ncol=3, dimnames=list(NULL, c("W", "X", "Y")))
> dat <- as.data.frame(dat)
> Z <- as.factor(rbinom(nrow(dat), size=1, prob=plogis(.2+.1*dat$W-.2*dat$X)))
> dat <- cbind(dat, Z=Z)
> ## W,X,Y: input
> ## Z: output
> dat.app <- dat[1:1e3, ]
> dat.val <- dat[1e3+(1:1e3), ]
> 
> ## ## h2o procedure
> dat.h2o.app <- as.h2o(dat.app) ## apprentissage

  |                                                                            
  |                                                                      |   0%
  |                                                                            
  |======================================================================| 100%
> dat.h2o.val <- as.h2o(dat.val) ## validation

  |                                                                            
  |                                                                      |   0%
  |                                                                            
  |======================================================================| 100%
> 
> library.h2o <- c("h2o.deeplearning.Tanh",
+                  "h2o.randomForest.1000x100")
> 
> h2o.model <- h2o.ensemble(y="Z", x=c("W", "X", "Y"),
+                           training_frame=dat.h2o.app,
+                           family="binomial",
+                           learner=library.h2o,
+                           cvControl=list(V=10, shuffle=TRUE),
+                           metalearner="h2o.glm.wrapper")

ERROR: Unexpected HTTP Status code: 400 Bad Request (url = http://127.0.0.1:54321/99/Rapids)

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
 [1] "water.rapids.ASTTmpAssign.apply(ASTAssign.java:254)"                                  
 [2] "water.rapids.ASTTmpAssign.apply(ASTAssign.java:248)"                                  
 [3] "water.rapids.ASTExec.exec(ASTExec.java:46)"                                           
 [4] "water.rapids.Session.exec(Session.java:56)"                                           
 [5] "water.rapids.Exec.exec(Exec.java:63)"                                                 
 [6] "water.api.RapidsHandler.exec(RapidsHandler.java:23)"                                  
 [7] "sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)"                          
 [8] "sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)"
 [9] "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)"                                     
[10] "water.api.Handler.handle(Handler.java:64)"                                            
[11] "water.api.RequestServer.handle(RequestServer.java:644)"                               
[12] "water.api.RequestServer.serve(RequestServer.java:585)"                                
[13] "water.JettyHTTPD$H2oDefaultServlet.doGeneric(JettyHTTPD.java:617)"                    
[14] "water.JettyHTTPD$H2oDefaultServlet.doPost(JettyHTTPD.java:565)"                       
[15] "javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)"                         
[16] "javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)"                         
[17] "org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)"               

Error in .h2o.doSafeREST(h2oRestApiVersion = h2oRestApiVersion, urlSuffix = page, :
    Temp ID RTMP_5 already exists
Calls : h2o.ensemble ... .eval.driver -> .h2o.__remoteSend -> .h2o.doSafeREST
Execution halted
```

I'm kind of lost there and don't understand the reason why it does not work now, the training set should be in the good format.
Did someone encounter this problem?if yes how did you get over this error?

Comment: Your code is not reproducible. h2o.deeplearning.Tanh and h2o.randomForest.1000x100 are unknown. The learner specs are not available. Btw, if I run the code with h2o.deeplearning.wrapper and h2o.randomForest.wrapper as learners it works.

Comment: ah sry forgot didn't include the other file where the random forest and tanh is..

Comment: code works on my machine. Can you try your code on a windows machine? And check if you have the latest version of the ensemble package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a bug in the recent version of the h2o R package, which has been fixed.  It will be patched in the next stable release of the h2o R package, or you can download the nightly release here: http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/master/latest.html

The problem stems from multiple calls to `h2o.init`.  For now, you can get around this error by shutting down all h2o instances and trying again with this in mind.

More info here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/h2ostream/E6u9YbWmD6k

Comment: Thx for the fast answer.

Comment: Using the nightly release does not solve this bug for me. Running on Mac OSX.

Comment: @timothyjgraham Please provide more info, and/or follow the bug report instructions on the h2ostream Google Group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/h2ostream

Comment: @ErinL. Thanks - have posted a bug report on the Google Group.